# Creating reverse of Inner glow when styling polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, style

In QGIS 3.22.1, the Inner Glow effects property (below) creates a sharp outer boundary that fades towards the inside.

[image]

I would expect that the Outer Glow effects property (below) would provide the "reverse" of the Inner Glow: a sharp polygon boundary fading to the *outside*.  However, it results in a glow to *both(!)* sides of the polygon boundary, with no sharp boundary delineation.

[image]

How do I create the reverse of the Inner Glow: a sharp boundary that fades to the outside?

I tried using the Inner Glow with negative Spread and Radius, but no joy.

Comment: This might be a bug actually, I would have expected the same behaviour. Please check on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues if there is something already and if not, file an issue.

Comment: Ok, I submitted this bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46496

Comment: I actually think this is expected behaviour with 'Outer Glow' applied to the entire polygon  and not just the boundary. If the 'Source' layer is of Symbol layer type - Outline: Simple line (rather than some kind of fill), applying Outer Glow does so to the boundary, albeit on both sides. For any kind of sharp boundary with the interior being transparent 'Inverted Polygons' seems to be the intended method/option.

Comment: You have a strong argument.  However, from https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#draw-effects I quote: *Outer Glow: This effect is similar to the Inner Glow effect, but it adds the glow effect on the **outside** of the edges of the feature. The available options for customization are the same as the Inner Glow effect.*  Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set layer rendering to `Inverted Polygons` and `Symbol layer type` to `Shapeburst fill` and under `Shading style` set a distance. Set the second color (here: white) to transparent to see the background:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a correct workaround.  Hurray!  However, it does not explain the unexpected *Outer Glow* behavior, for which I've submitted a bug report, as suggested by @bugmenot123.

Comment: I think Shapeburst is the intended way to do what you qant - glow effects are a workaround and not primarily intended for this.